# GuiceApplicationLoader configuration error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

So, I'm trying to implement compile time DI with something that looks like this:

```
package modules

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() {
    bind(classOf[MyT]).to(classOf[MyTImpl])
  }
}

class MyApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
  override protected def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
  initialBuilder
    .in(context.environment)
    .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration)
    .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
    .load(new MyModule)
  }
}
```

application.conf includes a line:

```
play.application.loader = "modules.MyApplicationLoader"
```

However, when I try to spin up the application, I get an error:

```
ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.Application was bound.
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error

No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.Application was bound.
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1042)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
....
```

Don't understand why this isn't working, as none of the examples I've seen for this do anything more involved. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bindings` instead of `load`:

```
class MyApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
  override protected def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
  initialBuilder
    .in(context.environment)
    .loadConfig(context.initialConfiguration)
    .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
    .bindings(new MyModule)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but that's not how compile time dependency injection works. Guice does its magic at runtime. However, if you want to have your dependencies ready as soon as the application starts, use eager loading. Guice already provides all the tools needed:

#### MyModule

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() {
    bind(classOf[MyT]).to(classOf[MyTImpl]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

#### application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.MyModule"
```

Because `MyTImpl` will be loaded as a singleton, it must have no instance bound data. Think of an `object` in scala terms. Always the exact same instance of `MyTImpl` will be injected.

Comment: It's just a minimal example. I needed to use different bindings depending on whether the application is in Prod or Dev mode (as we're mocking out services due to them usually not being available in Dev mode) - and preferably without the developer needing to switch between different conf files manually. Using play.modules.enabled doesn't work for that (at least by my understanding). Using bindings(..) works as I expected, and we're able to set up a case in the Loader to handle the different cases.

Comment: @MichaelA. One of DI's advantages, if not to say core features, is to wire together the application without touching the code. The use case you described is exactly what DI is made for. Have your read [Additional Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration)?