# No application loader is configured

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am running a Play application as described in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#using-the-sbt-assembly-plugin).

```
java -Dconfig.file='/home/me/production.conf' -jar target/scala-2.11/myplayapp.jar
```

And I get the following error, although I have juice included in my library:

```
libraryDependencies += guice
```

I appropriate help with that.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application loader is configured. Please configure an application loader either using the play.application.loader configuration property, or by depending on a module that configures one. You can add the Guice support module by adding "libraryDependencies += guice" to your build.sbt.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155680/guiceapplicationloader-configuration-error) post has any solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created a multimodule project and at some point decided to try to use guice library for a single module as it was the only module with play framework. Other modules are just plain Java projects. 
  I put

```
libraryDependencies += guice
```

to that module. Then the problem appeared. Even when I moved guice back it didn't help. The strange thing is that after I reverted project started to work if I use

```
 $sbt run
```

but it doesnt work in Intellij Idea. **To resolve it I had to reimport the project in my IDE.**